# Silencing -Wtype-limits and -Wbool-compare in code, without pragmas

Tags: c, gcc

When compiled with `gcc -Wall -Wextra`, the following code

boolcmp.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    #define TEST(X) do{if((X)>=0) puts("no minus");}while(0)
    TEST(1);
    unsigned u = 0; (void)u; 
    _Bool b = 0; (void)b;
    TEST(u); //-Wtype-limits
    TEST(b); //-Wbool-compare

}
```

generates `-Wtype-limits` (with `-Wextra`) and `-Wbool-comapare` (with `-Wall`) warnings as marked.

```
boolcmp.c: In function ‘main’:
boolcmp.c:4:27: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true [-Wtype-limits]
  #define TEST(X) do{if((X)>=0) puts("positive");}while(0)
                           ^
boolcmp.c:8:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘TEST’
  TEST(u); //-Wtype-limits
  ^~~~
boolcmp.c:4:27: warning: comparison of constant ‘0’ with boolean expression is always true [-Wbool-compare]
  #define TEST(X) do{if((X)>=0) puts("positive");}while(0)
                           ^
boolcmp.c:9:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘TEST’
  TEST(b); //-Wbool-compare
  ^~~~
```

Can these warnings be silenced from within the code without pragmas?

Comment: I doubt it.  In both cases, those warnings are pretty strongly suggesting that the code is *broken*.  What does it mean for an unsigned or a bool to be negative?

Comment: That code doesn't give me any bool-compare warnings, but I do get the type-limits warning.  I could silence the type-limits with `-Wno-type-limits`.  I figure the same should work for your bool-compare with `-Wno-bool-compare`

Comment: @SteveSummit It makes sense in a few of my macros.

Comment: I am now realizing you probably want to write the code in such a way as to not set off the compiler warnings, not just silence any compiler warnings of those types

Comment: This might be a good time to use `_Generic` to get rid of the conditional for `unsigned` and `_Bool` types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `_Generic`-based non-complaining replacement for an `X>=0` test:

```
#define MY_nominus_eh(X)  \
_Generic((X)+0LL,llong:my_spos_,ullong:my_upos_,default:my_fpos_)(X)
static inline _Bool my_upos_(ullong X) { (void)X; return 1; }
static inline _Bool my_spos_(llong X) { return X>=0; }
static inline _Bool my_fpos_(ldouble X) { return X>=0; }
//assumes: typedef long long llong; 
//typedef unsigned long long ullong;
//typedef long double ldouble;
```

Thanks to [Christian Gibbons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8513665/christian-gibbons) for the suggestion.

Later I found out I actually wanted the macro to expand to an *integer constant expression* (usable in `_Static_assert`'s) so I had to come up with something different.

The trick I used was to use `_Generic` to replace the suspiciously typed variable with an integer constant, which, while also leading to a tautological comparison, did not trigger gcc's warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    #define TEST(X) do{if( _Generic((X),_Bool:0,default:_Generic(+(X),unsigned:0,\
                    unsigned long:0,unsigned long long:0,default:X)) >=0) puts("no minus"); else puts("minus"); }while(0)
    TEST(1);
    unsigned u = 0; (void)u; 
    _Bool b = 0; (void)b;
    TEST(u); //-Wtype-limits
    TEST(b); //-Wbool-compare
    TEST(-1);

}
```

Comment: I like the use of `(X)+0LL` to take advantage of the integer promotion rules so you don't need a generic association for each of the unsigned types.